# How to get ONLY the Grand Total of Group Counts?

Tags: mysql

This code works great for getting both a summary of individual Group counts and a Grand Total combined, but I only want the Grand Total of individual countries with no ROLLUP:

```
SELECT country, count( * ) 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY country
WITH ROLLUP
LIMIT 0 , 300
```

Researching a lot of examples, I was hoping this one would finally work but no joy (can't figure out what the MySQL error is in the code):

```
SELECT country,COUNT(*)  
   FROM mytable 
   GROUP BY country 
   COMPUTE Sum(Count(*))
```

Thanks for any assistance!

-stucko

Comment: show us an example of data u have and result u want to recieve pls

Comment: because it sounds like u need `SELECT count( * ) 
FROM mytable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the number of rows returned by a `GROUP BY` you can do something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT country, count( * ) 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY country

) a /*derived tables need an alias*/
```

Comment: Thank you very much, chiliNUT - that was the solution and I learned something again!

Comment: @stucko NP! Consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: click the Green check mark up by the upper left of chiliNUT's answer.

Comment: The checkmark looks light gray here, but I'll try it.  Thank you both again.